# Yup validation not triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

Error message triggers for `name` field, but not for `description`:

My validation schema:

```
import { TFunction } from 'i18next';
import * as yup from 'yup';

export const getValidationSchema = (t: TFunction) => yup.object({
    name: yup
        .string()
        .required(t('promoName.required', { ns: 'validations' }))
        .max(70, t('promoName.maxLength', { ns: 'validations', length: 70 })),
    description: yup
        .string()
        .required(t('promoDescription.required', { ns: 'validations' }))
        .max(255, t('promoDescription.maxLength', { ns: 'validations', length: 255 }))
})
```

and these are the default values on the page with my form:

```
const validationSchema = getValidationSchema(t);
const defaultValues: IPromotionsAndDiscountsForm = {
    name: '',
    description: ''
};
```

my 2 MUI fields in the form:

```
<FormField
    name="name"
    label={t('promotionName', { ns: 'promotionsAndDiscounts' })}
    control={form.control}
    inputProps={{
        'data-testid': 'promoName',
        maxLength: 70
    }}
/>
<FormField
    name="description"
    label={t('promotionDescription', { ns: 'promotionsAndDiscounts' })}
    control={form.control}
    inputProps={{
        'data-testid': 'promoDescription'
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Did you set yup as a resolver while registering your form? Something like: ```const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });```